# How to change cakephp auth component controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Here my controller name is AucUsersController. After use auth component it is finding userscontroller.I want to change this directory.I have tried by bellow code but it's not working.

```
public $components = array('Paginator'=>array('limit'=>2),'Auth'=>array(
            'Controller'=>'AucUsers',
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'index'),
            'authError'=>'You can not access this page!!',
));
```

How can I change this default controller ?

Comment: Have you read this from the docs http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects; You do not create a controller. You create an Auth Component

Comment: After add auth component in appcontroller, by default it search a login action in userscontroller.But here I am using AucUsersController, so there have no any UsersController.After add Auth component in appcontroller now it's searching a userscontroller.But I haven't any userscontroller.

Comment: Sorry for that. I thought you wanted to make your own auth component.

Comment: you need to change loginAction in Auth settings it is by defualt users controller login action

Comment: May you tell me how I will change it ? @ Abhishek

Comment: @UmmeRaihana Check the answer i just added for more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP by default uses users/login for loginAction, 
loginAction is the property where you define the controller and action where cake does the login

```
public $components = array('Paginator'=>array('limit'=>2),'Auth'=>array(
            'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'aucusers',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'index'),
            'authError'=>'You can not access this page!!',
));
```

loginRedirect - It represents where user should redirect to after login
logoutRedirect - It represents where user should redirect to after logout

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want to change the default controller you have to set the `UserModel` option. I set it at beforeFilter method. So in your case it will be.

```
/**
 * beforeFilter method
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'AucUser',
        )
    );

    return parent::beforeFilter();      
}
```

I haven't seen in the docs to have any controller option.